# Problem with installing AWS CLI V2 on Centos 7 on a non standard centos username - permission denied. Sudo required

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I this aws cli working without the use of sudo?

steps to reproduce:
installing the aws cli 2
$ sudo ./install
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version

$ /usr/local/bin/aws
-bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: Permission denied

when i usesudo, it works
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.5 Python/3.8.8 Linux/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.centos.7 prompt/off

$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May 25 23:34 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/customuser/.local/bin:/home/customuser/bin

The thing is if I were to do the same on an Amazon Linux2, it works fine.
How do i make aws run without running sudo?

note that i have tried also installing aws cli in the /home/customuser/bin and it's the same where it says permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It worked after another try the next day despite running that same command before.

After installing which places your aws into /usr/local/bin

you run sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/aws-cli